# How to search completion list in zsh just like fish shell?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

In fish shell, I can use `Shift+Tab` to search completion list. But I don't know how to do that in zsh.

Comment: Literally the second google result for "zsh completion list search" is this being answered on the unix stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367693/fish-like-argument-completion-search-in-zsh

Comment: @ChrisKitching I found that answer. But they don't resolve my question.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is additional functionality from [zsh-users](https://github.com/zsh-users/) called [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions).

I've just started using this, and since I also have Homebrew, I was able to install it easily with `brew install zsh zsh-completions`. But the linked resource has many installation options and instructions.

When you're done installing you should probably run `source ~/.zshrc` and then you should see the effects.